# Displaying css on page load if already checked

Tags: javascript, css

I have the below code that works perfectly if you go back and re-click the radio button after page load.  I would like to see if there is a way that on page load it expands the css instead of having to re-click it if it is already clicked.  If ee1 is checked yes on page load then expand the showee.  So to recap, everything works fine but you have to re-click the radio to expand the table id so I think I need to modify my javascript.

Here is a complete working example on jsfiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/pinchetpooche/gnk5mpuv/1/

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>

.gads-yes { 
    border:none;
    background-color:transparent;
    outline:none;
}

.gads-no { 
    border:none;
    background-color:transparent;
    outline:none;
}

.gads-na { 
    border:none;
    background-color:transparent;
    outline:none;
}

.ee-yes { 
    border:none;
    background-color:transparent;
    outline:none;
}

.ee-no { 
    border:none;
    background-color:transparent;
    outline:none;
}

.gads {
    border:none;
    background-color:transparent;
    outline:none;
}

.content {
    display: none;
}

.none {
    border:none;
    background-color:transparent;
    outline:none;
}

.ee {
    border:none;
    background-color:transparent;
    outline:none;
}

.et {
    border:none;
    background-color:transparent;
    outline:none;
}

</style>

<script language="JavaScript">   
    /*Environmental Event*/

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#showee").css("display","none");
    $(".ee").click(function(){
        if ($('input[name=ee1]:checked').val() == "Yes" ) {
            $("#showee").slideDown("fast");
            $("#showet").slideDown("fast");
            $("#showspill").slideUp("fast");
            } else {            
                $("#showee").slideUp("fast");
                $("#showet").slideUp("fast");
            }     
    });
});

/*NonSpill Event*/
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#showet").css("display","none");
    $(".et").click(function(){

        if      ($('input[name=eventtype]:checked').val() == "Air" ) 
                { 
                 $("#showet").slideDown("fast"); 
                 $("#showspill").slideUp("fast"); 
                }

        else if ($('input[name=eventtype]:checked').val() == "Water" ) 
                { 
                 $("#showet").slideDown("fast");
                 $("#showspill").slideUp("fast"); 
                }

        else if ($('input[name=eventtype]:checked').val() == "Waste" ) 
                { 
                 $("#showet").slideDown("fast"); 
                 $("#showspill").slideUp("fast"); 
                }

        else if ($('input[name=eventtype]:checked').val() == "Spill" ) 
                { 
                 $("#showet").slideDown("fast"); 
                 $("#showspill").slideDown("fast"); 
                }

        else    { 
                 $("#showet").slideUp("fast"); 
                }

    });
});

</script>

</head>

<BODY>

<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="add_incident.asp">

<table border="0" class="formset" >

     <tr>
        <td width="125"><label for="ee1" class="style8">Enviromental Event?</label></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="ee1" value="Yes" class="ee" checked /><span class="style8"> Yes</span>
            <input type="radio" name="ee1" value="No"  class="ee"  /><span class="style8"> No</span> 
        </td>    
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>

</table>

<div>

<fieldset> 
<table id="showee" class="formset" align="left" border="0">
<tr>
<td>
        <table>
        <tr>
        <td width="100" align="left"><label for="eventtype" class="style8">Event Type</label></td>
        <td>
        <input type="radio" name="eventtype" value="Air"   class="et"/><span class="style8"> Air</span>
        <input type="radio" name="eventtype" value="Water" class="et" /><span class="style8"> Water</span>
        <input type="radio" name="eventtype" value="Waste" class="et"/><span class="style8"> Waste</span>        
        <input type="radio" name="eventtype" value="Spill" class="et"  /><span class="style8"> Spill</span> 
        &nbsp;        
        </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr> 
<td> 
        <fieldset>
        <table id="showet" align="left" border="0">  
            <tr>
            <td>

                <table>

                     <tr>
                        <td align="left" width="125"><span class="style8">Date of Event&nbsp;</span></td>
                        <td align="left" colspan="3"><input type="text" id="dateofevent" name="dateofevent" class="inputtext3">
                        <script language="JavaScript">
                        new tcal ({
                        'formname': 'form1',
                        'controlname': 'dateofevent'
                        });
                        </script>
                        &nbsp;
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                     <tr>
                        <td><span class="style8">Time of Event</span></td>
                        <td><INPUT TYPE="text" id="time1" NAME="time1" VALUE="" class="inputtext3" maxlength="4" onkeypress='validate(event)'></td>         
                      </tr>

                      <tr>
                        <td><span class="style8">Station</span></td>
                        <td>
                        <select name="station" id="station" class="drop7">
                            <option value=""></option>
                            <option value="A"><span class="style8">A</span></option>
                            <option value="B"><span class="style8">B</span></option>
                            <option value="C"><span class="style8">C</span></option>
                            <option value="D"><span class="style8">D</span></option>
                        </select>
                        </td> 
                      </tr>            

                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="4" align="right"><input type="submit" name="submit2" value="Submit" class="form_button_clear" /></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="6">&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>                 
            </table>


            <table id="showspill">   
                <tr>
                    <td class="style9" width="200">SPILLS MENU</td>
                </tr> 

                <tr>
                    <td class="style9">General Information</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td class="style8" width=133>Location of Spill</td>
                <td><input type="text" value=""  name="spillloc" class="inputtext5" /></td>                
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td class="style8" width=133>Person Who Reported the Spill</td>
                    <td><input type="text" value=""  name="spillperson" class="inputtext5" /></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td class="style8" width=133>Cause of Spill</td>
                    <td><input type="text" value=""  name="cause" class="inputtext5" /></td>              
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td colspan="4" align="right"><input type="submit" name="submit2" value="Submit" class="form_button_clear" /></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td colspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td colspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
            </table>

        </td>
       </tr>            
      </table>
     </fieldset>

</td>   
</tr>      
</table>
</fieldset>   

</form>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Kindly make runnable code.

***https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/***

Comment: "instead of having to re-click it if it is already clicked" - how can it be clicked on page.load, the user has no time to do that. You can set the checked attribute in the html to have it so by default

Comment: The attribute is checked properly but since it is an on-click event, it doesn't expand until it is clicked.  Purely a cosmetic thing for end users.

Comment: then just `$(".ee").trigger("click")` on `page.load` - voilà

Comment: I'm missing something here as well, how exactly should this line read?  $(".ee").trigger("click") on page.load (function(){

Answer (score 1):

U can use localstorage like:

```
localStorage.setItem("isChecked", $('input[name=ee1]:checked').val());
```

then

`if(localStorage.getItem("isChecked") == "Yes"){//do sth}`

Sth like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#showee").css("display","none"); 
   
   if(localStorage.getItem("isChecked") == "Yes") 
     slideDown();
   
   else{
     
     $(".ee").click(function(){
       localStorage.setItem("isChecked", $('input[name=ee1]:checked').val()); 
       if(localStorage.getItem("isChecked") == "Yes"){ 
         slideDown();
       } 
     else {
       $("#showee").slideUp("fast");
       $("#showet").slideUp("fast");
     } 
   }); 
     
    var slideDown = function(){
       $("#showee").slideDown("fast"); 
       $("#showet").slideDown("fast");
       $("#showspill").slideUp("fast"); 
    }
 });
```

Comment: You need to verify if `isChecked` has a value and if has and is "Yes" then expand or what you want - else do the click event

Comment: That is not working in the jsfiddle when I modify it with your code, also errors on the last line in dreamweaver.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it, albeit probably ugly and not the best way.  Same jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/pinchetpooche/gnk5mpuv/9/

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

    if ($('input[name=ee1]:checked').val() == "Yes" ) {
            $("#showee").slideDown("fast");
            $("#showet").slideDown("fast");                         
            }
    else {

    $("#showee").css("display","none");
    $("#showet").css("display","none");}
    $("#showspill").css("display","none");

    $(".ee").click(function(){

        if ($('input[name=ee1]:checked').val() == "Yes" ) {
            $("#showee").slideDown("fast");
            $("#showet").slideDown("fast");

            } else {                      
                $("#showee").slideUp("fast");
                $("#showet").slideUp("fast");
            }     
    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){

    if (!$('input[name=eventtype]:checked').val() == "Spill" ){ 
                 $("#showet").slideDown("fast"); 
                 $("#showspill").slideUp("fast"); 
                }
        else if ($('input[name=eventtype]:checked').val() == "Air" ) 
                { 
                 $("#showet").slideDown("fast"); 
                 $("#showspill").slideUp("fast"); 
                }

        else if ($('input[name=eventtype]:checked').val() == "Water" ) 
                { 
                 $("#showet").slideDown("fast");
                 $("#showspill").slideUp("fast"); 
                }

        else if ($('input[name=eventtype]:checked').val() == "Waste" ) 
                { 
                 $("#showet").slideDown("fast"); 
                 $("#showspill").slideUp("fast"); 
                }

        else if ($('input[name=eventtype]:checked').val() == "Spill" ) 
                { 
                 $("#showet").slideDown("fast"); 
                 $("#showspill").slideDown("fast"); 
                }       

 else {

    $("#showet").css("display","none");}

    $(".et").click(function(){

        if (!$('input[name=eventtype]:checked').val() == "Spill" ){ 
                 $("#showet").slideDown("fast"); 
                 $("#showspill").slideUp("fast"); 
                }
        else if ($('input[name=eventtype]:checked').val() == "Air" ) 
                { 
                 $("#showet").slideDown("fast"); 
                 $("#showspill").slideUp("fast"); 
                }

        else if ($('input[name=eventtype]:checked').val() == "Water" ) 
                { 
                 $("#showet").slideDown("fast");
                 $("#showspill").slideUp("fast"); 
                }

        else if ($('input[name=eventtype]:checked').val() == "Waste" ) 
                { 
                 $("#showet").slideDown("fast"); 
                 $("#showspill").slideUp("fast"); 
                }

        else if ($('input[name=eventtype]:checked').val() == "Spill" ) 
                { 
                 $("#showet").slideDown("fast"); 
                 $("#showspill").slideDown("fast"); 
                }

    });
});
```

Comment: I thought you need the value saved even if user refresh the page or comes back from another page to this one - I don't think that your code does that.